# Uninstall an extension in Contao 4

Tags: uninstallation, contao

I am working with contao 4. I created an extension and I need to uninstall it. How can I uninstall an extension in contao 4? 
I manually deleted the extension from system/modules. What are the other steps to be done to uninstall an extension?

Is there a way to recover system/cache folder in contao?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install or uninstall extensions manually in `system/modules` you also need to delete the cache manually. Simply delete the `var/cache` folder.

Optionally run a `cache:warmup` afterwards.

Comment: You should not remove that folder. Legacy extensions might use that folder.

Comment: Suppose that I uninstalled an extension manually and cleared the cache. Whether there is any chance of showing warning message on composer update for that module?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Why would the composer update show a warning?

Comment: I hope that it was because I haven't removed that module name from composer.json file.

Comment: Oh - you should _not_ manually delete extensions, that you installed via composer. In that case, simply execute `composer remove …` or remove the package from the `composer.json` and then execute `composer updae`. If you have manually removed an extension that was installed via composer for whatever reason, you should still remove the package from the `composer.json` and then execute a `composer update`. However, that might cause some errors, I am not sure.